# ExecStart fails running command npm run start but running it in directory works

Tags: node.js, unix, nvm, systemctl

This is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nodejs Server

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/projects
ExecStart=npm run start
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
After=multi-user.target
```

The error reads:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
 at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.j>
 at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
 at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
 at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/home/projects/node_modules/web3-core/lib/extend.js:24:14)>
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10>
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

It was working fine for months until I added a dependency in my package.json 2 days ago, specifically web3.

The weird issue is, when I go to my projects directory, and run npm run start, it works fine.

Not sure how it's possible that my service file produces a dependency issue, but running the server manually is working without issues.

Been using tmux since I've been experiencing this issue.

Running node v18 if that makes a difference. Not sure what the service file is doing differently than me running the command directly in the directory.

I tried to upgrade node version, removed node_modules and reinstalled, removed and reinstalled web3 package. As well as restarted the server.

Comment: forgot the [Unit] section at first line

Comment: Sorry the editor wasn't displaying it, but it's definitely there. Edited my question to fix it.

Comment: whats it the "start script" in package.json?

Comment: NODE_ENV=production nodemon app.js

Comment: if do you try to use node directly, whats happens? something like:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/projects/app.js

Comment: So your answer gave me an idea, it seems systemctl is using a different version of node than that which i intended using nvm. I used whereis node and modified the service file to use v18 of node to start the server. It's working as expected now, thanks alot for for the help!

Comment: @badrone Please add that as an answer instead of as a comment.